# Estimating Number Of normal subgroups of a p-Group

Tags: group-theory

Does someone have an idea about a possible way to count the number of normal subgroup that a group of order $p ^n $ has ($n \in \mathbb{N}$ )?
Is there anyway we can count the maximal subgroups it has (i.e.- the groups of order $p^{n-1} $ ? ) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Counting maximal subgroups is equivalent to counting p-cycles in the elementary abelian group $P/\phi(P)$.

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on the group, isn't it? Just among groups of order 8, the answer varies from 4 to 16.

Comment: In case you aren't the same person, there is a thread about this on MO.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/108581/108584#108584